# Firefox trigger quick find on typing in a page

Tags: firefox

I remember being able to do quick find in a page when I simply type something, instead of pressing '/' and then type.

Is there any setting which enables this? I recently did a reset Firefox from about:support and I believe it used to work before that. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're talking about [this feature](http://www.mozilla.org/access/type-ahead/), try with this parameter :

> user_pref("**accessibility.typeaheadfind.autostart**", true); // If true,
>   just typing can automatically start Find As You Type. If false, you
>   must hit / (find text) or ' (find links) before your search

Comment: accessibility.typeaheadfind.autostart was already true. To make it work I had to set accessibility.typeaheadfind as true whose default value is false.But as per the link you given it should have been enabled by default. Did firefox change this behavior?